# Python selenium return an empty element from div

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

The first thing I had to do was register on the website, and that went smoothly.
But now I want to extract the parameter with the value 99.73 using selenium:

```
<div class="collapsible-header notableborder testsetcontainer grey lighten-3" tabindex="0">
 <span class="strong">Parameter</span>
 99,73
</div>



driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = path)
driver.get(url)
element = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.collapsible- 
header.notableborder.testsetcontainer.grey.lighten-3")
print(element)
```

But it returns an empty field = []
Hope someone can help me.

Comment: I think your search parameter is too narrow, try too loosen it up a bit, first search for `div` then `collapsible-header`, then the combination. By doing this iterative, you can find the right input that works. Generally when doing this, you would like to search on only 1 or 2 parameters, which makes the whole process more robust.

Comment: it does not work.. can you give me some more advices ?

Comment: For me the css selector `.grey` is enough to select your element. I created a fake page with your `<div> ... </div>`, and used `driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".grey")`. For the exact parameter values you can use: `driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".grey")[0].text`, which returns `'Parameter 99,73'`.